# On my Windows 7 PC The Free Space Is Going Up and Down

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, local-storage

On my Windows 7 PC the free space on the local disk is increasing and decreasing automatically, and I haven't installed anything recently.The total space of my local disc is 39.00 GB.It is going up and down by a few megabytes.THE Last software what I installed was an antivirus program naming ESET.I didn't understand the problem first.So I have deleted some files from local disc which seems unnecessary to me.Can it fall a impact on this case?

Comment: Please add additional detail to your question. For example, How big is your disk total? How much is it increasing / decreasing by megabytes or gigabytes? When was the last time you installed something on your computer and what was it?

Answer (score 0):

Fluctuations of a few MB would be consistent with temp files / caches and should generally be nothing to worry about.

Do you have Windows auto update itself? Downloading the update will take space. When if you have it configured to manually trigger the update it may be downloading those files in the background

Do you use a web browser on that computer. If so it may cache files from the webpages it visits. Other programs also write temp file and not all then are good about cleaning up after themselves.